# mysql function IF(DAY(customers_dob) = DAY(current_date), true, false) AS today doesn't work with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following query

```
$stmt = $db->query("
  SELECT   CONCAT(customers_firstname, ' ', customers_lastname) name,
           customers_dob AS dob,
           IF(DAY(customers_dob) = DAY(current_date), true, false) AS today,
           IF(MONTH(customers_dob) = MONTH(current_date), true, false) AS month,
           YEAR(current_date) - YEAR(customers_dob) AS year
  FROM     " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . "
  WHERE    MONTH(customers_dob) = MONTH(current_date)
  AND      DAY(customers_dob)  >= DAY(current_date)
  ORDER BY customers_dob
");
$birthdays = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

works fine with mysql extension in PHP and it gives a result in phpMyAdmin.

With PDO I get only this array

```
Array
(
  [name] => Max Mustermann
  [0] => Max Mustermann
  [year] => 44
  [1] => 44
)
```

the key 'today' and 'month' is missing.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: "`ers_lastname) name`" is missing an `AS`. You're also not getting 'dob'

Comment: First reduce your example to the single case where it fails. Everything else is not helpful to ask on a Q&A site. Additionally make clear that you do proper error checking and which SQL mode you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't aliasing the concatenation of first name and last name correctly - you're missing the `AS` keyword.  Change:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(customers_firstname, ' ', customers_lastname) name,
```

to:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(customers_firstname, ' ', customers_lastname) AS name,
```